# I have thousands of test cases written in Jmeter 2.11 in using soap webservice configuration. I am getting "Test element is obsolete"

Tags: jmeter

I see Apache Jmeter has deprecated SOAP webservice calls. How do I migrate these thousands of testcases with configuration to use http. Please help. Apache Jmeter provided an alternate solution as 
to use in jmeter 2.11 a JMeter 5.0 as proxy so that it records the request. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **JMeter 5.0 as a proxy for JMeter 2.11**, if you're looking for exact steps:

1. Start JMeter 5.0
2. Prepare JMeter 5.0 for recording. The fastest way is via [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature) feature, From its main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"

   [image]
3. Expand [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and click "Start"

   [image]
4. Run your script in [JMeter 2.11 using JMeter 5.0 as a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) as:

   ```
   /path/to/jmeter2.11/bin/jmeter -H localhost -P 8888 -n -t test.jmx
   ```
5. JMeter 5.0 will capture the executed SOAP requests in form of [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

Comment: I cannot view images in above answer. Can you please help?

Comment: Images are hosted on https://imgur.com/, most probably you have something which blocks access to that site

Comment: This is not working for me. How do i execute the soap test cases written in 2.11? All the test elements shows obsolete. Cannot access?